# Does a C for-loop exit on encountering a '\0' character?

Tags: c, hash

I was going through a hash function and encountered a condition where the for loop
 is supposed to exit when a '\0' (NIL) character comes.

```
unsigned int hash_string (const char *s)
{
    register unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0; *s; s++) { // This for loop is supposed to end
                           // when a '\0' comes?
        i *= 16777619;
        i ^= *s;
    }

    return i;
}
```

As far as I know a C-Loop is supposed to end ***if a condition returns `0`***.
Here, however, there is no such condition and it still works?
Could someone also tell on what all conditions does a loop succed/fail?

Comment: @juanchopanza Any citations from C standards?

Comment: I added an answer with a reference.

Comment: Proper style is `*s != '\0'`. Crappy style is `*s`.

Comment: @Lundin well, this method is from GNU Bash.

Comment: @yadav_vi Crap is crap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The null character has the value of `0`, so in your example, `*s` will evaluate to zero if it corresponds to the null termination of the character string.

From **5.2.1 Character sets**

> ... A byte with all bits set to 0, called the null character, shall
>   exist in the basic execution character set; it is used to terminate a
>   character string.

Then in **6.4.4.4 Character constants**

> 12 EXAMPLE 1 The construction `'\0'` is commonly used to represent the
>   null character.

Comment: So as all the bits are set to `zero`, `\0` is equivalent to `0`?

Comment: @yadav_vi In this context, yes, although `0` is an integer literal, so the number of bytes might be different. But `\0` and `0` would compare as equal.

Comment: So the compiler takes care of it?

Comment: Yes. `if ('\0')` is always false.

Answer (score 1):

`*s` de-references the character pointed by `s`.

If the character code is `0` the loop breaks and it passes for all values other than `0`.

`\0` is guaranteed to be `0`, that why it is guaranteed that loop will terminate at string end when it encounters NUL character.

One of the reason for choosing `\0` as string termination in `C` is to make constructs like this possible.

Comment: Could you cite something from C standards?

Comment: `null character shall have the code value zero.` according to `7.19 Common definitions <stddef.h>` from n1570 C11 specs

Comment: Also from **5.2.1.2**: `A byte with all bits zero shall be interpreted as a null character independent of shift
state. Such a byte shall not occur as part of any other multibyte character` and **6.4.4.4**: `Example 1: The construction '\0' is commonly used to represent the null character`

Answer (score 1):

When `*s` evaluates to `0` or `false`, which is convertable from one another, the loop ends.

In fact, the integer representation for character `\0` is `0`. So it's the same thing.

Comment: I am aware that the string should be `NULL` terminated, but that isn't my question here. As a matter of fact, it is ensured that all the strings passed to it are `NULL` terminated. (I found this function in GNU bash implementation.)

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. I corrected it now. I think NULL-terminated means by definition the character `\0`, whose integer representation is `0`.